# CALL statement syntax error when passing multiple parameters mySql

Tags: mysql, database, syntax-error

I am running a query in MySQL 5.6.11. I have created a following stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `digital_audio_test_detail`(IN temp VARCHAR(50), IN temp2 VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
    SET @temp_query = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM ',temp);
    SET @final_query = CONCAT(@temp_query,'WHERE', temp,'.unit_test_result_id =',temp2);
    PREPARE stmt FROM @final_query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
END
```

When I call this procedure in my query page, I get syntax error at its CALL. This is how I execute my queries.

```
SELECT unit_test_result.*, @temp1 := unit_test.name, @temp2 := unit_test_result.id 
FROM unit_test_result, unit_test 
WHERE unit_test_result.test_run_id = 2 
  AND unit_test.id = unit_test_result.unit_test_id;
CALL digital_audio_test_detail(@temp1, @temp2);
```

I have to pass two parameters to the procedure. When I create a procedure with only first parameter and CALL it one parameter, it executes fine. But When I do with two parameters I get syntax error. Need help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
SET @final_query = CONCAT(@temp_query,'WHERE', temp,'.unit_test_result_id =',temp2);
```

The string you are building is not a valid query.

Add space before and after WHERE, as in

```
SET @final_query = CONCAT(@temp_query,' WHERE ', temp,'.unit_test_result_id =',temp2);
```